# how to run different jobs in jenkins depending upon success or failure of upstream job

Tags: jenkins

I have 3 Jenkins jobs, Job A, Job B and Job C.

If Job A passes, I want to run Job B else Job C.

Could someone please help me in achieving this configuration in Jenkins. Is there any plugin that i can use?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

You can set a Post-build action on the Job A configuration as below:

*Trigger parameterized build on other projects:*

```
Projects to build : Job B
Trigger when build is : Stable
Tick - Trigger build without parameters

Projects to build : Job C
Trigger when build is : Failed
Tick  - Trigger build without parameters
```

[image: Job A Configurations]

Comment: I think you can add only one build other projects block for a project. After adding one "build other projects" block when i go to add other one, it's grayed out for me.

Comment: I am sorry for rushing to respond without checking the solution. Sometimes over willingness to respond can cause untested solutions ;). I have now corrected the respond providing the correct solution I use for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think one can add only one build other projects option in post build actions. Due to this limitation i did solve my issue as follows:

1) Added build other projects option in post build actions of JOB A. Selected JOB B to run only when build is stable (This is to handle the condition: when JOB A is passed, run JOB B)

2) Downloaded a Jenkins plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin

Added Build other projects (extended) option in post build actions of JOB A. Selected JOB C to run when build result is equal or under UNSTABLE (This is to handle condition: When JOB A is failed, run JOB C.)

Please let me know if there are any other ways.